# Spock testing a ResultSet in Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, tdd, resultset, spock

Here is what I have so far:

```
def "If there are results then return true otherwise return false"() {
    given:
    ResultSet resultSet = Mock()

    expect:
    resultSet.next()
}
```

I am trying to test a boolean method `checkIfRowExists(int id, int foreignKey)`  in class `CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl`. It returns true if row exists and false otherwise.

How would I go about solving this?

```
public boolean checkIfRowExists(int id, int foreignKey){
    Resultset resultSet = checkIfRowExistsResultSet(id, foreignKey)

    return false;
}
```

The above method doesn't have the correct implementation as of yet because I'm trying to write the test first before I implement the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Think we would need to know what `CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl` looked like... How does the method have a resultset? There doesn't seem to be anything passed in the method definition

Comment: It calls a private method named checkIfRowExistsResultSet(int id, int foreignkey) I'll update... thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were on your place I would do the next TDD steps.

1. Start with a test for one test case only:

   ```
   def "If there not are results then return false"() {
       given:
       def service = new CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl()

       expect:
       !service.checkIfRowExists(1, 2)
   }
   ```
2. Implement the method to satisfy the test:

   ```
   boolean checkIfRowExists(int id, int foreignKey) {
       return false;
   }
   ```
3. Add new test for case when there are some result:

   ```
   def "If there are results then return true"() {
       given:
       def service = new CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl()

       expect:
       service.checkIfRowExists(1, 2)
   }
   ```
4. Now we are forced to implement our method. The method will do a DB query and check the actual result set for emptiness. Because the DB query is out of unit test scope we extract it to a separate method and will override it in the test later:

   ```
   boolean checkIfRowExists(int id, int foreignKey) throws SQLException {
       ResultSet resultSet = getResultSet(id, foreignKey);
       return resultSet.next();
   }

   ResultSet getResultSet(int id, int foreignKey) {
       return null; // TODO should be implemented
   }
   ```
5. Now our test is failed with `NullPointerException` because `getResultSet()` returns `null`. Lets return a mocked `ResultSet` which returns `true` on `next()` call:

   ```
   def "If there are results then return true"() {
       given:
       ResultSet mockedResultSet = Mock(ResultSet)
       mockedResultSet.next() >> true

       def service = new CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl() {
           @Override
           def ResultSet getResultSet(int id, int foreignKey) {
               return mockedResultSet;
           }
       }

       expect:
       service.checkIfRowExists(1, 2)
   }
   ```

   The test is green now.
6. The first test is to be fixed as well, mock to return `false` on `next()` call:

   ```
   def "If there not are results then return false"() {
       given:
       ResultSet mockedResultSet = Mock(ResultSet)
       mockedResultSet.next() >> false

       def service = new CheckActuateProjectSetServiceImpl() {
           @Override
           def ResultSet getResultSet(int id, int foreignKey) {
               return mockedResultSet;
           }
       }

       expect:
       !service.checkIfRowExists(1, 2)
   }
   ```

Hope it will help. These steps are just an orientation to move forward in TDD style. Sure things your reality is different and may require something more specific that I proposed above.

Comment: This is perfect. I just needed to know how to go about it. Thanks.